# Got this from a API using curl

Tags: php, curl

Trying to add some kind of value to each data point so I can send the response (numbers only) to an existing table .  I've been searching online and no CURL API response seems to be this simple so I can find an answer. (sorry new to this, don't know the "lingo")

This is the response I've been able to echo on screen.

"{"price": 2049.27, "change_point": -5.76, "change_percentage": -0.28, "total_vol": "1.27M"}"

rest of php below

```
<html>
<?php

    $url = 'https://realstonks.p.rapidapi.com/';
    $collection_name = $_REQUEST["stock_name"];
    $request_url = $url . '/' . $collection_name;
    $curl = curl_init($request_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [

    'X-RapidAPI-Host: www.xyz.com',
    'X-RapidAPI-Key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'Content-Type: application/json']);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);



    //Uncomment bellow to show data on screen
echo $response . PHP_EOL;

    enter code here

//var_dump(json_decode($json));
//var_dump(json_decode($json, true));


//  Initiate curl
$ch = curl_init();
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
// Execute
$result=curl_exec($ch);

// Closing
curl_close($ch);


 ?>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Looks like you've got a JSON string in `$response`. What do you want to do with?

Comment: I want to add to <td>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much into PHP but here to here. If I'm not mistaken it, I think you want to store `$response` in `<td>` element. This resource can help **https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/428730/how-to-display-php-variable-in-html**